# Why doesn't const A & bind to A() in template arguments?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this template instantiation but it's not working. I'm getting the errors:

> `prog.cpp:7:15: error: template-id 'f<const A&, A()>' for 'void f()' does not match any template declaration`

```
template <class T, T> void f() {}

struct A {};

template void f<const A &, A()>();

int main() {}
```

This is weird, because when I do it in main it works:

```
int main() {
    const A &a = A(); // no error
}
```

So why doesn't it work in the template line?

Comment: What do you expect `A()` to do as a *template* argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-type template parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters)

These are the rules of template non type parameters

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

What you are passing is an RValue (temporary object, etc which cannot be assigned to), which does not fall under any of these possibilities.

### edit:

It appears that it is infact being interpreted as a function type, but your template signature expects a non type parameter of type `A` (exactly a `const A&`)

Comment: It is not an rvalue, it is parsed a function type.

Comment: @Pubby: even without a return type? it is not parsed as a call to default constructor?

Comment: @KarthikT the return type is `A`.

Answer (score 2):

A template argument cannot be a temporary object. Only primitive types which can reasonably be compared for exact equality may be template non-type arguments. This includes

- integers,
- enumerators, and
- pointers to objects with `extern` linkage.

But

- floating-point numbers aren't allowed because they can be very close yet not equal
- `static` objects might have the same name but different locations in different files, which would make the template-id confusingly resolve to different instantiations with the same name in different files
- same goes for string literals
- temporary objects don't have consistent addresses so you can't pass a pointer to one
- the value of a temporary object as you passed, which can't even be tested for equality, would never let the language match one template instantiation to another!

(As Pubby notes, `A()` is actually interpreted as the type of a function with no parameters returning `A`. So the compiler is just failing to find a template declaration taking two type parameters.)