# Template variable `list` doesn't working?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class:

```
template <class T, list<int> t> 
class Tops
{
private:
    list<stack<T>> tops;
public:
    list getTops() {

    }
};
```

It doesn't compile as: `illegal type for non-type template parameter 't'`,

On line 6: `template <class T, list<int> t> class Tops`.

When I change the `list<int>` to type `int` , it working. what is the problem?

Comment: Exactly what the error says - `std::list` is not a valid non-type template parameter. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5687553/500104).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `template <class T, list<int> t>` to `template <class T, list<int> &t>`:

```cpp
template <class T, list<int> &t>   
                             ^^^  //note &t
class Tops
{
private:
    list<stack<T>> tops;
public:
    list getTops() {

    }
};
```

The reason you can't do this is because non-constant expressions can't be parsed and substituted during compile-time. They could change during runtime, which would require the generation of a new template during runtime, which isn't possible because templates are a compile-time concept.

**Here's what the standard allows for non-type template parameters (14.1 [temp.param] p4):**

```
A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following 
(optionally cv-qualified) types:

 - integral or enumeration type,
 - pointer to object or pointer to function,
 - reference to object or reference to function,,
 - pointer to member.
```

Source Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687553/1906361

Answer (score 0):

Parameter of  `template` is resolved at compile time.

Template arguments must be constant expressions, addresses of functions/objects/static members or references of objects.

I think you're looking for this :

```
template <class T,list<int> &t> 
class Tops
{
private:
    list<stack<T>> tops;
public:
    list<stack<T> > getTops() {

    }
};
```