# Type of Template Parameters (For function Templates) : C++

Tags: c++

I was reading this tutorial:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/144-expression-parameters-and-template-specialization/

and it was mentioned `However, template type parameters are not the only type of template parameters available. Template classes **(not template functions)** can make use of another kind of template parameter known as an expression parameter.`

So I wrote a program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    template<typename T,int n>
    bool Compare(T t,const char* c)
    {
    if (n != 1)
    {
     cout << "Exit Failure" << endl;
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

    bool result=false;
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << t.compare(c) << endl;
    if(t.compare(c) == 0)
    result = true;

    return result;
    }




int main()
{
    string name="Michael";

    if (Compare<string,1>(name,"Sam"))
    cout << "It is Sam" << endl;
    else
    cout << "This is not Sam" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

And got the Output:

```
$ ./ExpressionParameter
Sam
Michael
-1
This is not Sam
```

Clearly, here the template parameter is taking `int n` as `expression parameter`. So the point mentioned in the tutorial `Template classes (not template functions) can make use of another kind of template parameter known as an expression parameter.` seems to be incorrect.

Further reading at

[Non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters)

also suggest the same.

So what I have understood is that: no matter if it is function template or class template, the template parameter could be `template type parameter i.e. typename` or `expression parameter`. The only constraint is that , for expression parameter - it must be `constant integral expression`. The compiler does not differentiate if it is for `function` or `class`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've never heard of a function template not being able to have non-type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you seem to understand this correctly.

One use case of this is to write generic code but still get the benefits of a compile-time constant (such as better compiler optimizations).

One example is [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which takes such a template `size_t` parameter for its length. Another example is [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), which uses a `bool`.