# Template typename as type of other parameter of the same template

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create a template, where i can use different vector types, and a constant as the same type of the vector. 
I would like to able to pass the constant as template parameter in order to let the compiler optimize it, without explicit specialization.

So i tried to re-use the type parameter, but i got illegal type.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename WEIGHT, WEIGHT multiplier>
void test_multipier(vector<WEIGHT> &v)
{
    uint16_t num = 16;
    /*...*/
    WEIGHT w = multiplier* (num);
    v.push_back(w);
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> test_vector;

    test_multipier<double,0.01>(test_vector); 
    //^^ Error C2993 'double': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'multiplier'


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A non-type template parameter cannot be of floating point type. Pass it as a second argument instead.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) :

> [A non-type template parameter's type] is one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored):
>
> - `std::nullptr_t` (since C++11);
> - integral type;
> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
> - pointer type (to object or to function);
> - pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> - enumeration type.

`double` cannot be used as a non-type template parameter.