# Unable to compile class with a template parameter

Tags: c++

I have some very simple code, which looks like so:

```
template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
class One
{
    T *p;
};

template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
class Two
{
    One<One<T, DEFAULT>, DEFAULT> *p;
};
```

When I try to compile it, I get an error message:

> error: 'class One' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

When, however, I change `const T DEFAULT` to `typename T2` and `DEFAULT` to `T2`, it starts working:

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
class One
{
    T *p;
};

template <typename T, typename T2>
class Two
{
    One<One<T, T2>, T2> *p;
};
```

But, it is not what I want. I need my first variant of code work, but I do not know what is wrong with that and how can I fix it.

Comment: Only primitive types like `int` or `bool` can be used as non type template parameters. Provide a specialization for `One` instead.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters

Comment: Well, as the compiler told you, you can't use type `One<T, DEFAULT>` for non-type template parameter. Your second example is completely different since it uses type parameter instead of non-type parameter.

Comment: Beyond `One<T, DEFAULT>` not being a valid type for a non-type template parameter, there's also the issue of `DEFAULT` *not being* of type `One<T, DEFAULT>` (as `One` requires). This smells like an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
> class One
> {
>     T *p;
> };
>
> template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
> class Two
> {
>     One<One<T, DEFAULT>, DEFAULT> *p;
> };
> ```

There are a couple problems with this:

1. `DEFAULT` isn't the same type as `One<T, DEFAULT>`; `DEFAULT` is of type `T`. Thus you can't use `One<One<T, DEFAULT>, DEFAULT>`.
2. Only a few types are [valid as template non-type parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter). Quoting cppreference:

   > - std::nullptr_t (since C++11);
   > - integral type;
   > - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
   > - pointer type (to object or to function);
   > - pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
   > - enumeration type.

`One<T, DEFAULT>` is not one of the above, so it can't be used as a template non-type parameter

Comment: And If T in my case is supposed to be of integer type, can I somehow provide some default specialization, like @TheDude suggests?

Comment: @Jacobian If `T` is supposed to be an integer type, yes you can do that. You just need to ensure that the non-type parameter is of an integer type. You may be interested in [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)

Comment: @Justin Unfortunately the cppreference doesn't state that `double` or `float` types are also not allowed, or don't these count as _integral types_?

Comment: @TheDude ["Types bool, char, char16_­t, char32_­t, wchar_­t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types."](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-7.sentence-1)

Comment: @TheDude `double` and `float` aren't [integral types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). They are [arithmetic types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks for the reference. Good to know.

Comment: @Justin. "If T is supposed to be an integer type, yes you can do that.". Would you be so kind to elaborate on this a little bit in your answer and provide some tiny example to show how it works?

Comment: @Jacobian IMO, that's a different question. It's also answered elsewhere on the site. But the easiest thing to do might be a `static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "<error message>");` in the body of `One`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
> class One
> ```

The second `T` refers to the first one and is the type of the non-type template parameter called `DEFAULT`.

For example, you could instantiate the `One` template like this:

```
One<int, 12345> // T is int, DEFAULT is 123456
```

Or like this:

```
One<char, 100> // T is char, DEFAULT is 100
```

Or like this:

```
One<int*, nullptr> // T is int*, DEFAULT is nullptr
```

Those examples have in common that `T` must be a valid non-type template argument. You could not, for example, use a type template argument for it:

```
One<std::string, 123> // fails, because `std::string` cannot be used as `DEFAULT`
```

Now if you look at your second class...

> ```
> template <typename T, const T DEFAULT>
> class Two
> {
>     One<One<T, DEFAULT>, DEFAULT> *p;
> };
> ```

In the attempted outer instantiation of `One`, `T` would be `One<T, DEFAULT>`. And that's exactly like the `std::string` example above; `One<T, DEFAULT>` isn't a non-type template argument.

There is no "fix" for this, because the concept of your `Two` class is fundamentally broken.