# Non type template parameter of type std::string& compiles in gcc but not in clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I am learning C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I learnt that we cannot use `std::string` as a non-type template parameter. Now, to further clear my concept of the subject I tried the following example which compiles in gcc and msvc but not in clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rdKexW9fE)

```
std::string nameOk[] = {"name1", "name2"};
template<std::string &name>
void foo()
{
   
}
int main()
{
    
    foo<nameOk[0]>(); //this compiles in gcc and msvc but not in clang in C++20  
}
```

**My question is** which compiler is right here(if any). That is, is the program well-formed or IFNDR.

Comment: It seems odd to allow a non-`const` `std::string` to be passed as a template parameter...

Comment: @ShadowRanger We can pass a nonconst global `std::string`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687575/12002570) where this is shown.

Comment: First of all note that you are not using `std::string` as the template argument, you're using `std::string&`, which is allowed. Secondly, it seems to be a bug in Clang that it doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes **I already know that `std::string` is not a valid nontype template parameter as written at the beginning of my question**. Kindly read the question again. That is the reason I tried `std::string&` and was surprised that it does not compile in some compilers. Also, I'm looking for an authoritative answer.

Comment: The accepted answer in the post @JasonLiam refered to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters/5687575#5687575) quotes the standard regarding non-type template parameters. _"lvalue reference to object"_ is one of the options there.

Comment: Sounds like Clang isn't implementing the newest wording, which AFAICS permits subobjects as non-type template arguments (as opposed to C++14/17)

Comment: @JasonLiam: Neat. Strange, but neat. :-)

Comment: Include your error message in the question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clang is complaining that your template argument is a subobject. (If you make the argument a complete string object, it works.)

This behavior is based on an earlier restriction in the standard at [temp.arg.nontype], which read

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject (6.7.2 [intro.object]),

This restriction is lifted as of [P1907](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html) which is in C++20, but Clang hasn't reflected that yet. GCC also fails when you use e.g. version 10 with C++17:

> `error: '& nameOk[0]' is not a valid template argument of type 'std::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'} because 'nameOk[0]' is not a variable`

Comment: At the end of your answer you're telling that it fails with gcc version 10 and c++17. But that is the intended behavior since the restriction wasn't lifted in c++17 but only in c++20.

Comment: @JasonLiam Exactly, that's why it confirms my hypothesis that GCC deliberately enabled this from later standard versions onwards...

Answer (score 3):

Clang is wrong in rejecting the code as this is allowed by the standard. From [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#6):

> **6)** A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (possibly cv-qualified) types:
>
> **6.1)** a **structural type** (see below),

> **7)** A **structural type** is one of the following:
>
> **7.2)** an lvalue reference type, or

(emphasis mine)

This means that `std::string&` can be used as a nontype template *parameter* for which `nameOk[0]` is a valid nontype template *argument* and the program is well-formed.